# Quotient set of $\mathbb R^2/SO(2)$

Tags: group-theory, quotient-set

I am trying to understand quotient sets with an example of rotations in the plane. I have seen that $\mathbb R^2/SO(2)\cong \mathbb R_{>0}$. As I understand this, the quotient set is the set of orbits or equivalence classes, i.e. the set of subsets of the plane that belong to the same orbit under the action of $SO(2)$. In this case, the orbits can each be labelled by a radius $r$.

I am wondering if the quotient set $\mathbb R^2/SO(2)$ is the set of radii, which is just the non-negative real line or is it sets of subsets of all the points that lie on a given circle? More generally, is the quotient set a set of labels or a set of sets?

$$
[r_1,\dots,r_n]\qquad [[x_1,\dots,x_m],\dots[y_1,\dots,y_m]]
$$

If they are distinct, how does the  universal property or G-invariant maps work in this case, if there was a function that mapped points in the plane to the orbit radius $f:\mathbb R^2\rightarrow \mathbb R$, that was a $G$-invariant map and a function $\tilde f:\mathbb R^2/SO(2)\rightarrow \mathbb R$ from the quotient set.

Comment: So I was thinking that $SO(2)$ rotates elements of the plane around in a circle.

Comment: $SO(2)$ is a group of $2\times2$ matrices, while $\Bbb R^2$ is a group of pairs of numbers. Not sure then how $\Bbb R^2/SO(2)$ can be thought of as a quotient, because $SO(2)$ is not a subgroup of $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: @Devo Thank you for that clarification. I am just learning this, so apologies if I'm not explaining myself correctly. By my notation, I mean that $X/G$ is a quotient set induced by the action $\rhd$ of group $G $ on set $X$, such that $X/G=\{G\rhd x\mid x\in X\}$. However, I might be confusing myself as I also see $G\backslash X$ written in different resources for the same quotient set.

Comment: Ah, I think we are on slightly different tracks, I mean quotient of the action of $G$ whilst you mean quotient groups. Apologies for that.

Comment: No problem, it's clear now.